# Complete Tutorial and Sample Application for TwitPic API

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, twitpic

can any one tell me complete tutorials links for TwitPic api.i have searched many.i dint get them. please share if any one knows the answer. kindly help me regarding this.

Comment: can anyone give me sample application on this.?please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer a this following site: [adding-twitpic-to-your-application](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/02/23/adding-twitpic-to-your-application/)

Comment: can anyone give me sample application on this.?please help me.